# Apache2 proxy reverse broken Tomcat8 links

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

In my DigitalOcean vps, I have Apache2 (LAMP), phpmyadmin and Tomcat 8. Everything is running well.
Now I'm trying to implement the reverse proxy so I can access the tomcat8 not by https://mydominiam.com:8080 but by https://mydominiam.com/tomcat. After reading some tutorials, I can get this code in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin mydomain@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/user/ssl/mydomain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user/ssl/mydomain.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/user/ssl/intermediate.crt 
 # AJP configuration
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /tomcat ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
 ProxyPassReverse /tomcat ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
 ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / / 
</VirtualHost>
```

The way the code above is when access https: //mydomain/tomcat, the tomcat home appears, but with broken links.

But if I change the code:

```
 ProxyPass /tomcat ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
 ProxyPassReverse /tomcat ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
```

for

```
 ProxyPass / ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
 ProxyPassReverse / ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
```

The tomcat home reloads usually no broken links, but only through the url https: //mydomain.com

I tried to follow [this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatModProxyHTML) tutorial, but it still fails. Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ProxyPass` with a Tomcat application where you are trying to rewrite the context path (in your configuration above, changing `/tomcat` to `/`), there are many many ways your application can break.

It is best to use a configuration like this:

```
ProxyPass /tomcat ajp://mydomain.com:8009/tomcat
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat ajp://mydomain.com:8009/tomcat
```

Now, deploy your application as `/tomcat` instead of the ROOT context. You can easily do that by re-naming the WAR file from `ROOT.war` to `tomcat.war` (or re-name the exploded WAR directory from `ROOT` to `tomcat`).

If you do the above, you don't have to play any games with rewriting links within pages, etc.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested to me but to https: //mydomain.com/tomcat the homepage tomcat 8 does not appear anymore and I get error 404.

This seems so simple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @sThiago Updated the answer: you'll need to re-name your webapp to change the context path. Are you trying to access Tomcat's default application, or one of your own?